# R populate list with samples

Tags: r, list

I have a numeric vector stock_data containing thousands of floating point numbers, I know i can sample them using

```
sample(stock_data, sample_size)
```

I want to take 100 different samples and populate them in a list of samples.

How do i do that without using a loop to append the samples to a list?

I thought of creating a list replicating the stock data 100 times then using lapply on them.

I tried:

```
all_repl <- as.list(rep(stock_data,100))
all_samples <- lapply(all_repl, sample, size=100)
```

But **all_repl** doesn't contain a list of data, it contains a single numeric vector which has replicated the data 100 times.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong and point out a better method to do what i want.

Comment: `replicate(100, sample(stock_data, sample_size)` may be

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `replicate`

```
replicate(100, sample(stock_data, sample_size))
```

Using `simplify=FALSE` get the output in a `list`.  Using a reproducible example

```
replicate(5, sample(1:9, 5), simplify=FALSE)
```